# Display all output but highlight search matches

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

In bash, if I want to execute a command and only display output lines that matches a certain pattern, I can pipe it to `grep`, like

file testfile

```
hello
there
my
friends
```

command

```
$ cat testfile | grep 'hello'
hello #this will be highlightd
```

this will highlight the search match and display the entire line it falls on.  I can use `-A` and `-B` to display lines before and after that line.  My question is is it possible to execute the command and display all output as normal, but to highlight the search matches like grep would?  so my ouput would be

```
hello #highlighted
there
my
friends
```

Comment: See [Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/366/80216) (U&L) or [Colorized grep — viewing the entire file with highlighted matches](//stackoverflow.com/q/981601/3960947) (Stack Overflow) for better answers.

Answer (score 91):

To use a Color GREP to only highlight matched patterns but not otherwise change the output:

```
grep --color=always -e "^" -e "hello" testfile
```

The first pattern will match all lines (all lines will be printed) the second pattern (and any following patterns) cause the matched text to be highlighted in color.

Since the first pattern matches all lines but does not match on a printable character, it does not add any color highlighting so it doesn't compete/interfere with the readability of the highlighted text.

Comment: Works with kubectl `kubectl apply -k .  | grep --color=always -e "^" -e "configured"` in zsh

Comment: For use in Bash: highlight() { grep --color=always -e "^" -e $* ; }

Comment: This works on FreeBSD as well, you just need to swap the first and the second patern (`"^"` needs to be second).

Comment: Very smart! Thanks! Have my upvote!

Comment: I like this version: `egrep --color "^|hello" testfile`

Comment: @Jon Thanks for that, worked perfectly for me in zsh.

Answer (score 41):

Add option `-z` to your GNU grep command:

```
cat testfile | grep --color=always -z 'hello'
```

or shorter

```
grep --color=always -z 'hello' testfile
```

Comment: This is a very crude hack.   It has the effect of treating the entire file as a single line.   Therefore, (1) if the file is very large, there may be a possibility of running out of memory, and (2) if the file doesn’t contain the pattern *at all*, then nothing will be output.

Comment: What version of grep is this supported on?  On grep 2.5.4, -z doesn't seem available...

Comment: @Alex: I used GNU grep version 2.6.3.

Comment: @G-Man: more resource-saving: `grep --color "hello\|$" file`

Comment: @Cyrus: Yes, that’s a better answer. Unfortunately, it is essentially equivalent to [bot779’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/914856/354511#1192944) to this question, and almost identical to the accepted answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981831/3960947#981831) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366/80216#367)) to the questions I linked to.

Comment: @G-Man: Thanks for the hint. I missed that.

Comment: For whatever reason this doesn't work with kubectl in zsh

Answer (score 10):

This one works with GNU grep as well as with grep on FreeBSD:

```
grep --color=always 'hello\|$'
```

It matches the text "hello" or (`\|`) the non-printable null string at the end of each line (`$`). That's why each line gets printed but only "hello" is highlighted.

Chances are you already have `--color=auto` configured in your shell. Then you most likely don't need to specify `--color=always`:

```
grep 'hello\|$'
```

You can also simpler version by using `egrep` (with extended regular expressions), where `|` for the "or" expression doesn't need to be escaped:

```
egrep 'hello|$'
```

See also similar question on StackOverflow: [Colorized grep -- viewing the entire file with highlighted matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches)

Comment: This doesn’t answer how to display all the input lines.

Comment: @ChrisPage I would say it does: *That's why **each line gets printed** but only "hello" is highlighted.*

Comment: To be pedantic — _"the non-printable null string at the end of each line"_ — There is _**not**_ a "non-printable null string" (`0x00`) at the end of lines, there is a _line-terminator_ / end-of-line which will generally be `0x0d`, `0x0a`, or `0x0d0x0a` (CR, LF, CRLF)

Comment: You are confusing a null string with a null character (`\0`). Null string is an empty string. The term null string is taken from the regex documentation. See for example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

Answer (score 8):

Similarly to previous answer, you can catch all `$` end of lines:

```
cat testfile | grep --color -E "hello|$"
```

`-E` (or `--extended-regexp`) means that special characters must be escaped with `\`. When using it, `|` will be treated as regex "OR" condition.

Grep `|$` will also catch and print all lines which has an end, but since $ is a hidden character, it cannot be highlighted.

**Update:**

If you'd like to **print all output, but also return exit code**, whether match was found or not, you can use perl command:

```
cat testfile | \
perl -pe 'BEGIN {$status=1} END {exit $status} $status=0 if /hello/;'
```

If you prefer **sed** - Here's an example how to **highlight all matches + return exit code** if no match found:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1200851/670392

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using `ripgrep`, a modern, easier to use (IMO), and much faster replacement for `grep`:

```bash
cat my-file | rg --passthru '<REGEX>'
```

---

You can also easily customise the "highlighter colour":

```bash
# dark red foreground with light yellow background:
cat my-file | rg --passthru --colors match:fg:124 --colors match:bg:229 '<REGEX>'
```

See `man rg` ([online version](https://manned.org/rg.1)).

---

For everyday use I created a shell alias:

```bash
# in .bashrc
alias hl='rg --passthru --colors match:fg:124 --colors match:bg:229'
```

Now it's as simple as `cat my-file | hl '<REGEX>'`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the top answer above. The highlight{} function mentioned in the comments only works when data is piped into it. The following alias, while not perfect, is more useful:

```
alias greph="grep --color=always -e^ -e"
```

This works with commands such as:

```
greph foo bar.txt

cat bar.txt | greph foo
```

Answer (score 0):

`-z` is good to output the entire file as in the answer from `bot779` but most times you need to control how many lines you want to include above and below the match. You can control the length of context with `-C <N>` where N is the number of lines of context. See the example below:

```
cat >testfile <<EOM
hello
there
my
friends
more
lines
to demonstrate
context
EOM

cat testfile | grep --color=always -C 2 friends

there
my
*friends* highlighted
more
lines
```

Using a large number such as `-C 1000` can also limit the output if the output you are filtering is too big.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this than using the `--color` option as all the other answers suggest.  Use the [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command.  Example:

```
cat my_file.txt | tee >(grep 'search_for_this')
```

This will display the full contents of `my_file.txt` and all instances of `search_for_this` will be highlighted.